# There is no Baire bijection between $\mathbb R$ and the set of functions $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb R$ modulo shifts

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ denote the set $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ (the set of all functions from integers to reals), 
and $\sim$ the equivalence relation on $X$ defined by:

$f \sim g$  iff there is a $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that for all $z' \in \mathbb{Z}: f(z'+z) = g(z')$.

Consider the quotient set $X/\sim$.

Some years ago, Mike Oliver made the remark that no bijection between $X/\sim$ and $\mathbb{R}$ could possibly be a Baire function.

I could do with a hint (or two) on how to prove that.

Comment: My apologies - my browser had/has some trouble with the MathJax preview.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$; just look at $2^\mathbb{Z}$.

Hint 1: any set $A\subseteq 2^\mathbb{Z}$ which has the Baire property and which is $\sim$-saturated (in the sense that $x\in A$, $x\sim y$ implies $y\in A$) must be either meager or comeager.

Hint 2: if $f : 2^\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$ is Baire-measurable and constant on every $\sim$-equivalence class, think about what $f^{-1}(U)$ could be, where $U$ ranges over open sets.  Maybe do something with a countable basis for $\mathbb{R}$...

I hope this is enough of a hint.